# View classes in a .NET library

Tags: c#, class, dll

I am trying to access function calls exposed by an application.  I was told that I should be able to view the classes in the .NET library.  I am guessing these would be in the .dll files.  I used Dependency Walker to open the .dll files, but did not see anything interesting.  Can you let me know a way to view classes in a .NET library?

Comment: C tag removed. Also, questions that ask for a tool are not well suited for SO.

Comment: Viusal studio shows them nicely, just add to a Project (References) and double-click.

Comment: You mean something like .net reflector, dotPeek.

Comment: I tried opening the dll in Visual Studio (File Open - File) and it brought up the dll in its own tab, but did not seem to show classes or function calls.

Comment: Read my comment again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside Visual Studio you can use the Object Browser.  Under the `View` menu, select `Object Browser`.  From there you can click the ellipses in the window and browse to a DLL.

This view will show you the public namespaces, classes and methods inside those classes.

[image: Object Browser]

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on a member in Visual Studio and go to (or peek) the definition, though this will only show you the API, not the implementation.

[ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) can inspect and decompile managed assemblies.

For standard .NET libraries from Microsoft, [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) is a great resource.

Comment: How do I open in Visual Studio?  I tried File Open - File but this opened the dll in it's own tab but did not show anything.

Comment: I generally navigate there from my own code. For example, if my source file has a call to System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World") then I can right-click on the word "Console" and go to definition. See also @henk-holterman's comment above about double-clicking on references.

Comment: I am looking at dll's that I did not create.  These are from a third party.  I am trying to see the function calls they expose.